# VS Code python interpreter issues

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a problem with two different windows 10 machines, where when attempting to run python code in VS code I get the Following error:

```
-bash: C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/python.exe:
No such file or directory
```

That is the correct and current path my current python install, and I have tried different versions as well.

I have already tried editing the path in VS code for the interpreter. and changing the windows path variable on both machines.

Comment: Did you try using backslashes instead of forward slashes? Also what did you set Windows path to? Windows path should be same except without \python.exe. To verify path in VS code go to File -> Settings -> type "python path". Windows path can be checked by opening a terminal -> choose powershell -> type "$env:Path". Also make sure correct Python interpreter is chosen in case you have multiple installed. CTRL+SHIFT+P -> Python: Select Interpreter